# Grep needs to match a specific word

Tags: shell, unix, grep

I want to use grep in a bash script to get the line with only the word "version" from a file, the problem is that a few lines further down in the file that i want the script to look in there is another line with the word "dlversion".

I am piping the grep into a cut command, the output will be saved as a variable

The problem is that it either saves nothing into the variable or it saves both lines, I've already tried several methods that i found, though none of them have worked.

```
grep -Fx version /path/to/file.txt | cut -c9-
```

output = nothing

```
grep '^version$' /path/to/file.txt | cut -c9-
```

output = nothing

```
grep "version" /path/to/file.txt | cut -c9-
```

output = both lines

also tried

```
grep -w "version " /path/to/file.txt | cut -c9-
```

output = nothing

I also tried to use -F, -x on their own which also caused the variable to not have a value.

Comment: It seems that using boundaries might help you: "\bversion\b".

Comment: Thank you, i changed the `cut` to start at the first character, then piped the output of the first `grep` through a second one using `-v` filtering out the remaining letters and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options, depending on your version of grep.

If supported, the best option is to use word boundaries `\b` either side of your word:

```
grep '\bversion\b' /path/to/file.txt
```

Or:

```
grep '\<version\>' /path/to/file.txt
```

Where `\<` and `\>` match the empty string at the start and end of a word respectively.

Otherwise, you can create your own set of characters that you consider to not be a word:

```
grep -E '(^|[[:space:][:punct:]])version' /path/to/file.txt
```

This matches "version", preceded by either the start of the line or any type of space or punctuation.

In your specific case, you could use something like this:

```
grep -E '(^|[^l])version' /path/to/file.txt
```

This matches "version" preceded by either the start of the line or anything other than an "l".

In response to your comment:

- `^` matches the start of the line.
- `|` means "or".
- `[^l]` is a bracket expression, where the `^` as the first character means "not" (so this matches every character other than "l").
- The parentheses are used to create a group, so that the "or" only applies to this part of the pattern.

Comment: Thank you! The version of grep I'm using doesn't support boundaries. The answer you suggested worked though. And since I'm curious and want to understand things i could potentialy use later on, could you explain what the `^|` and the `[^l]` do exactly?

Answer (score 1):

In case any sophisticated tricks fail, use the brute force: pipe the result through another `grep` process to filter out the lines with unwanted words (use `-v` option for that):

```
grep 'version' sourcefile | grep -v 'dlversion' > destination
```